# Gravity Turn initial ascent

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rocket-science

When executing a gravity turn a rocket will generally first ascend vertically to around 10000m. I need to calculate this initial stretch while knowing the specifics of the rocket and how high I want to go. However this means that I don't know how much time the rocket is flying for. Below equation can be used to describe the flight, but I'm failing to transform it so I get t.

$$
 v_R(t) = v_E ln \bigg(\frac{1}{1 - \frac{Rt}{m_{Ri}}}\bigg) − gt
$$

To further clarify:
At the beginning the following values are given: $v_E, g, R, m_0, h_0, h_1$. 
For now I ignore atmospheric drag and assume constant thrust, fuel flow and gravity.


I would be very glad for any help given, especially if you also manage to make me understand how you got to the solution.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please [do not make your post look like a revision table](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5886/25301), instead just seamlessly integrate the new material into the post. There is an edit history button at the bottom of the post for those interested in seeing what changed.

Comment: Oh, I've seen several posts use with the Edits in the text and never thought to check for a history feature. Thanks for telling me!

Answer (score 1):

OK, well, I can't completely understand your question but I can tell you where the formula you quote comes from and how to turn it into height.

First of all, for a rocket moving without gravity, there is a famous equation called the [Tsiolkovsky rocket equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation) which tells you what its velocity change is in terms of a few things.  This equation is:

$$\Delta v = v_e \ln\left(\frac{m_o}{m_f}\right)$$

Here

- $\Delta v$ is the change in velocity;
- $v_e$ is the velocity of the rocket's exhaust;
- $m_o$ is the original mass of the rocket (the 'wet mass');
- $m_f$ is the final mass of the rocket.

### With constant gravity

We can adapt this in two ways.  Firstly if the rocket is moving vertically upwards in a constant gravitational field with gravitational acceleration $g$ (which is a good approximation close to the Earth), then we can just add a $-gt$ to this expression, where $t$ is the time the burn takes:

$$\Delta v = v_e \ln\left(\frac{m_o}{m_f}\right) - gt$$

And secondly if we assume the rocket burns fuel at a rate $R$, then $m_f = m_o - Rt$ and we can plug this in:

$$\Delta v(t) = v_e \ln\left(\frac{m_o}{m_o - Rt}\right) - gt$$

And this, as I've indicated, gives us $\Delta v(t)$: $\Delta v$ as a function of time.

Finally, we can assume that, at $t=0$ $v=0$ and so we get an expression for velocity as a function of time:

$$v(t) = v_e \ln\left(\frac{m_o}{m_o - Rt}\right) - gt$$

We can rearrange this a little using properties of logarithms, mostly to make the next step easier, and get something which is the same (up to a sign corresponding to a reciprocal inside the $\ln$) as the expression you found:

$$v(t) = - v_e\ln\left(1-\frac{Rt}{m_o}\right) - gt$$

Just to be clear: this expression is valid for:

- a rocket moving vertically;
- under constant gravity $g$ (so near a planet);
- with no drag;
- burning fuel at a constant rate $R$.

So, OK, that is velocity as a function of time.  We'd like *height* as a position of time.  This is just the integral of velocity.  Assuming that $h(0) = v(0) = 0$, then

$$
\begin{align}
 h(t) &= \int\limits_{\tau=0}^t v(\tau)\,d\tau\\
      &= \int\limits_{\tau=0}^t\left(- v_e\ln\left(1-\frac{R\tau}{m_o}\right) - g\tau\right)\,d\tau
\end{align}
$$

So this leaves us with the small problem of doing this integral.  Well, you can do that and you get, I think:

$$
\begin{align}
 h(t) &= v_e t\left(1 - \ln\left(1-\frac{Rt}{m_o}\right)\right)\\
     &\quad +\frac{v_e m_o}{R}\ln\left(1-\frac{Rt}{m_o}\right)\\
     &\quad -\frac{gt^2}{2}
\end{align}
$$

So this is the height of the rocket as a function of time, with the above assumptions.

### With real gravity

I think this is much harder.  First of all we can set up the rocket equation as a differential equation.  In the absense of gravity (any gravity), but assuming a constant burn rate $R$ then the force on the rocket is $v_e R$, and the mass of the rocket at time $t$ is $m_o - Rt$.  So you can plug this into $F=ma$ to get

$$v'(t) = \frac{v_e R}{m_o - Rt}$$

And integrating this with respect to $t$ gives you the normal rocket equation.

But $v'(t) = h''(t)$ assuming the rocket is moving upwards and height is $h$.  And gravity acts downwards, with $g(h) = GM/(h+h_0)^2$, where $h_0$ is the height at $t=0$, $G$ is the ravitational constant, and $M$ is the mass of the Earth, so we can write the above, with the additional gravity term as

$$\frac{d^2 h(t)}{dt^2} = \frac{v_e R}{m_o - Rt} - \frac{GM}{(h(t) - h_0)^2}$$

And I think this is the right equation for a rocket moving upwards under gravity.  I have not attempted to solve this.

---

**Disclaimer**: check my working before using any of this.

Comment: +1, but note that this equation assumes no air resistance and constant thrust.  The equation for $h(t)$ would be different if one of those assumptions was relaxed;  it's not sufficient to just replace $R$ with $R(t)$.

Comment: Yes.  I suspect strongly that the realistic case can only be attacked numerically (although there might be less idealised special cases which have closed forms I suppose: I don't know): I was just explaining what to do with the equation he had really (I've just updated it to explicitly mention there's no drag)

Comment: @tfb I have edited my post to hopefully clear up what you don't understand about the question. The real problem I'm facing is, that I don't know how much time passes, only how high the rocket goes.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert The air resistance is being neglected and the thrust is constant. I've edited my post to clarify that.

Comment: @Promeign:  If you know the mass of the rocket at the start and end of the vertical ascent, and you know the rate $R$ at which mass is being ejected, then the time elapsed is just $t = \Delta m/R$.

Comment: I think if you allow g to vary with height then the rocket equation for $v(t)$ turns into a differential equation for $h(t)$ which might be $h'(t) +t g(h(t)) + v_e \ln (1-Rt/m_o)  = 0$ and I'm not even going to try to solve that.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I don't know the mass at the end of the ascent, only the rate at which it is expended as a function of time. Basically I'm shooting myself in the foot here, aren't I?

Comment: @Promeign: Ah, I see what you're aiming for.  If you know $h$, $v_E$, $R$, and $m_0$ in the final equation above, then that will determine $t$.  It's unlikely that you'll be able to write down an explicit formula for $t$ as a function of these quantities, but you could implement a simple [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) solver to find it.  Once you know $t$, you can then find the final mass and the final velocity.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert You mean let it run to the desired h, right? Do you have any recommendations for the size of the steps?

Comment: I've added a section which I think has the right equation for $h(t)$ with realistic gravity (the one in my comment was wrong).  I haven't attempted to solve it however (I suspect it is only soluble numerically).